# JS acting differently when logged in

Tags: javascript

I am trying to remove a class from inside my navigation menu.

When not logged in, the class is removed. However, when logged in as an authenticated user or administrator, the behavior changes and the class is not removed.

All my other jQuery code works, but not when trying to remove this class. I have been working all day at this trying all kinds of different approaches to target the class I want to remove with no luck.

The class I'm trying to remove is `.visually-hidden`.

HTML:

```
<li class="level-1">
<a>Link 1-A</a>
<ul class="menu visually-hidden">
    <li class="level-2">
        <a>Link 2-A</a>
        <ul class="menu visually-hidden">
            <li class="level-3">
                <a class="is-active">Link 3-A</a>
            </li>
            <li class="level-3">
                <a>Link 3-B</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="level-2">
        <a>Link 2-B</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
(function ($) {
  'use strict';

  Drupal.behaviors.themeJS = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
      var isActive = $('.is-active');
      isActive.parentsUntil('level-1').removeClass('hide-menu');
      isActive.closest('li').children('ul').removeClass('hide-menu');
    }
  };
  $.noConflict();
})(jQuery);
```

The scripts when not logged in:

```
<script type="application/json" data-drupal-selector="drupal-settings-json">{"path":{"baseUrl":"\/","scriptPath":null,"pathPrefix":"","currentPath":"node\/14","currentPathIsAdmin":false,"isFront":false,"currentLanguage":"en"},"pluralDelimiter":"\u0003","user":{"uid":0,"permissionsHash":"2dab5eb25c9e6a6f51b06a09a3e186667ade2001f679e71ff82ee2db9657d9f2"}}</script>
<script src="/core/assets/vendor/domready/ready.min.js?v=1.0.8"></script>
<script src="/core/assets/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js?v=2.2.4"></script>
<script src="/core/misc/drupalSettingsLoader.js?v=8.3.7"></script>
<script src="/core/misc/drupal.js?v=8.3.7"></script>
<script src="/core/misc/drupal.init.js?v=8.3.7"></script>
<script src="/themes/custom/sc_theme/js/theme.js?v=8.3.7"></script>
<script src="/themes/custom/sc_theme/js/jQueryRotate.js?v=8.3.7"></script>
```

The scripts when logged in:

```
<script type="application/json" data-drupal-selector="drupal-settings-json">{"path":{"baseUrl":"\/","scriptPath":null,"pathPrefix":"","currentPath":"node\/6","currentPathIsAdmin":false,"isFront":false,"currentLanguage":"en"},"pluralDelimiter":"\u0003","user":{"uid":"6","permissionsHash":"856ca48d12c0a856148b853636901b560e0fc56271ca1e4caa6a7ee9f34938bb"}}</script>
<script src="/core/assets/vendor/domready/ready.min.js?v=1.0.8"></script>

<!--[if lte IE 9]>
<script src="/core/assets/vendor/classList/classList.min.js?v=2014-12-13"></script>
<![endif]-->
<script src="/core/assets/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js?v=2.2.4"></script>
<script src="/core/misc/drupalSettingsLoader.js?v=8.3.7"></script>
<script src="/core/misc/drupal.js?v=8.3.7"></script>
<script src="/core/misc/drupal.init.js?v=8.3.7"></script>
<script src="/themes/custom/sc_theme/js/theme.js?v=8.3.7"></script>
<script src="/themes/custom/sc_theme/js/jQueryRotate.js?v=8.3.7"></script>
<script src="/core/misc/active-link.js?v=8.3.7"></script>
```

Comment: It might be a cache issue. Try clearing your cache. Reasons: if you check `/admin/config/development/performance`, you might see the 'Cache pages for anonymous users' checked. If that's true, your code could only possibly work in that cache.

Comment: Yes, I've thought of this and I've cleared the cache many times.

Comment: I've also cleared the cache on the browser (chrome) as I've seen this clear up javascript issues in the past.

Comment: Thank you! That worked. My js file is now loaded after `active-link.js` and everything is working regardless of logged in status. Thank you so much! Add this as the answer, and I'll mark it.

Comment: Yes, the difference is, that logged out `active-link.js` is not used, for anonymous the class is set in Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\ActiveLinkResponseFilter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `active-link.js` is loaded after your `theme.js` file when you are logged in as @4k4 mentioned. This means that the `.is-active` class does not exist until after your code is run.

Two ways come to mind:

1. Add a higher weight to `theme.js` so that it'll be run after `active-link.js`. See [the "Weighted JavaScript" Section](https://www.drupal.org/node/756722).
2. Run your code after everything is loaded. E.g. `window.onload`

Comment: I had a similar issue and `window.onload`solved it.